# How to tell whether a javascript variable is an Array and only an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

what's the best way to determine whether a Javascript variable is an array, but has no other user-defined properties? 'instanceof Array' doesn't do this.

e.g.

```
var var1 = [10,11];
var1['key1'] = 'extraProperty';

var1 instanceof Array;    //returns true
```

Comment: This will be hard. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: Please, tags in titles and thanks in posts are redundant. Don't write them.

Comment: I want to print out a javascript variable, using object notation where its a general object and array notation where its a pure array

Comment: @spiderplant0: `JSON.stringify(var1)` gives you array notation, despite and without the extra property, really.

Comment: @Kooilnc. Thanks, but I looked at stringify but it wasnt up to the job as I need more control (limiting recursion depth, dealing with cyclic data structures etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var isOnlyArray = function(o) {
    if (! (Object.prototype.toString.call(o) === "[object Array]")) {
        return false;
    }
    for (property in o) { 
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            var asInt = parseInt(property, 10);
            if (!(0 <= asInt && asInt < o.length)
                || String(asInt) !== property) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This function confirms that it's an `Array` and that every defined property on an object is an integer index that's in the range specified by `.length`.

```js
var a = [1, 2];
console.log(isOnlyArray(a)); // true
a[2] = 4;
console.log(isOnlyArray(a)); // true
a["foo"] = 5;
console.log(isOnlyArray(a)); // false
```

Comment: This is what I was going to write, but I think `o instanceof Array` would be better for your first conditional.

Comment: @Reid If you use iframes, that can produce false result if you can an `Array` from another `window`. This is less elegant, but more reliable.

Comment: @Jeremy, a small note: resolving just `toString` is assuming that the global object inherits from `Object.prototype`, and this is implementation dependent, for example, it won't work on any IE version (JScript) and some versions of Firefox 3.x. I would recommend you to refer to the method directly (`Object.prototype.toString`) or getting it in another way (e.g. `({}).toString`, IIRC some implementations are optimizing this case, by not creating the new object). Cheers and +1.

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy but it doesnt seem to work. your first example returns false.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention a problem on the usage of the relational operators (`if (!(0 <= asInt < o.length)`), that wouldn't work like in some other languages -e.g. Python-, in Javascript, the first comparison is made (`0 <= asInt`) and it will yield a boolean value, that will be converted to Number for the second comparison:`x < o.length` the value of x will be always 0 or 1 (from the boolean conversion) you would need to do the two comparisons separately, but by knowing the limits and behavior of Array objects, I would just ensure that the property name represents a 32-bit unsigned integer.

Comment: All this effort ... for what? Let's say I declared `a['0012'] = 'newprop'`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can verify the integrity of something that was created as an `Array` object. Javascript won't prohibit you from adding properties to such an object.

You *could* iterate through the object's properties and return `false` if you see one that you don't think should be in `Array`, but that's still no guarantee that even the normal properties haven't had their values mangled.

Just don't add properties to `Array`s, then you won't have this problem. That you're asking about this kind of implies that you've done something quite wrong somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, but I'm having to parse code written elsewhere. And, as is usual in real word scenarios, it would be naive to assume it will adhere to specific good coding guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't distinguish array and object. Object can be used as an array and vice versa. Example:

```
var fancyObj = {
    favoriteFood: "pizza",
    add: function(a, b){
        return a + b;
    }
};
fancyObj.add(2,3); // returns 5
fancyObj['add'](2,3); // ditto.
```